# Quick search icon spins forever after upgrading from 4.4 to 4.5

Tags: drupal, ajax

The upper-left quick search box and the edit-in-place for contacts spin the loading icon forever but never do anything. Looking in the browser console, there is a JavaScript error. It worked just fine on 4.4 but stopped after the upgrade to 4.5. I'm using the latest version of Drupal 7 in a multi-site setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using multi-site Drupal, check the Image Upload URL in Civi to be sure it's not set to https://[domain]/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/. In a multi-site setup there is no such thing as a 'default' site.

The quickest way to determine if this is your problem is to visit the CiviCRM dashboard and check the browser console for a 404 error on arrow.png. You will notice that the URL to the png file starts with https://[domain]/undefinedpackages/. Or try to use an ajax-powered feature and receive a JS error like "'back' is undefined".

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are some [troubleshooting steps](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html) for fixing non-responsive ajax or broken javascript in CiviCRM.